# Button makes the page jump down

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to create a simple slideshow for the site im working on.
Whenever I click on the button, the page jumps down. So how do I create an anchor so that when the user clicks the button it will stay on that section of the page?

```
<div class="slider-holder" >
    <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
    <div class="image-holder">
      ......
    </div>
    <div class="button-holder">
        <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

added some parts of the css - in hopes it will give more insight

```
  .slider-holder
    {
        width: 1114px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 0px;

    }

    .image-holder
    {
        width: 6000px;
        height: 200px;
        position: relative;

        -webkit-transition: left 2s;
        -moz-transition: left 2s;
        -o-transition: left 2s;
        transition: left 2s;
    }

    .slider-image
    {
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #slider-image-1:target ~ .image-holder
    {
        left: 0px;
    }

    #slider-image-2:target ~ .image-holder
    {
        left: -1114px;
    }

    #slider-image-3:target ~ .image-holder
    {
        left: -2228px;
    }
```

......

I'm pretty new to it and i've looked around for some similar questions that was asked around here but nothing worked I would appreciate any help :)

Thank you

Comment: The named anchors you created are doing exactly what they were designed to do. I you want to make a slideshow you'll need to use JavaScript to hide/show your images.

Answer (score 0):

Make the container of the image the anchor, not the image itself. I'm assuming you are showing 1 image at a time. If you are you could use bootstrap's carousel.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/